# Is possible to patch a linux executable to include a new so library?

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

I have this linux executable which loads some so libraries and I want to know if is possible to patch it with ida for example and makes it include a new library?

It is a game server and it loads a so library which have functions for each skill, I want to duplicate the so library, include it together with the original and edit function skill numbers in the duplicated so library. So I can add new skills to the game. Is that even possible?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. If you need to ask, you don't want to try. Binary level hacking is *hard*.

Comment: ok, how I include the duplicated so library?

Comment: You look at the code that parses the dynamic linking information contained in the ELF, and then use that knowledge to add an entry there for your new library.

Comment: ok I found a tool elfpatch that allowed me to link a new shared library to the main executable with just 1 line in the console. Now I get errors , I think it is because I have duplicated function names now... is there a easy way to set export functions to non-export? so then I can rename just 1 change it back to export and see if it doesn't crash?